# Is there a way to permanently disable updates of all Google software?

Tags: google-chrome, google-updates

Is there a way to stop updating Google Chrome, Picasa, Google Desktop, Sketchup - all Google products?

Comment: why do you want to do that?

Comment: @Sathya: I can think of two scenarios: 1. A slow internet connection. A couple of years ago, automatic updates would render my internet connection unusable. 2. Problems with the latest version. I never had that problem with Google, but Adobe is another story...

Comment: @Sathya: There's an old saying, you may have heard it: "If it ain't broke, don't fix it"

Comment: @AdrianPronk doesn't apply because you don't know what's broken or how bad.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Yes, there is.

Steps:

1. Press <kbd>Win</kbd> + <kbd>R</kbd> and execute `regedit`.
2. Go to `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Policies\Google\Update`.
3. Add/modify the DWORD `DisableAutoUpdateChecksCheckboxValue` and set it to `1`.

(Source: [How to Customize or Disable Google Update](http://googlesystem.blogspot.com/2009/05/customize-or-disable-google-update.html))

Make sure you update at least Chrome periodically to fix vulnerabilities.

Comment: Does Other Software Giants Like Yahoo , Microsoft or Other use the same thing for updating??? means they are using registries to check out update or not...

Comment: Microsoft probably does (they store *everything* in the registry), but it's easier to modify the updating behavior from the Control Panel. As far as I know, the only way to "disable" Yahoo!'s updates is to remove/rename `yupdater.exe`.

Comment: why they are not providing GUI Based something ... like in firefox only when we click "Check For Updates" then only it will check..

Comment: You'll have to ask them. I suppose it's because they *don't want you* to disable the automatic updates. Periodic updates are necessary to keep the system secure, and most people can't be trusted with manual updates.

Answer (score 3):

You can disable the check for updates in task scheduler.

You could find out what up or a record the updates are done via and block them in your hosts file.

Comment: this is actually a LOT simpler and avoids messing with the registry. +1

Comment: I remember doing this a long time ago, and if my memory serves me, this method didn't work very well. Every time you install a new Google product (and maybe every time you run a Google product), the task will be reenabled.

Answer (score 2):

Alternatively you can install and use the Chrome versions that do not have an automatic update feature like Chrome Canary and Chromium.

The difference between the two to update the build:

- With Canary, you have to click on the "Customized and control Google Chrome" button (it's the button with 3 dark horizontal bars at the top-right of the browser) then click on "About Google Chrome".
- With Chromium, you must actually download and install the update build. -

Please note that both Canary and Chromium are designed for early-adopter and developers so they may occasionally have issues although they always have the cutting-edge features ahead of all other versions.

Answer (score 0):

Try removing Google Auto Update service:

1. Hold window key with R key; it will bring the Run window.
2. Type `cmd` then hit . This will bring up the command window. 
   c. Type `sc delete gusvc`  then hit . You will get confirmation of the service deleted.